# Does equalsAny filter work on JSON field of custom entity?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I'm using a custom entity (Blog) in my app, it has a field JSON format that contains list of product ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/System/CustomEntity/Xml/entity-1.0.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_entity_blog">
        <fields>
            <!--...-->
            <bool name="status" store-api-aware="true"/>
            <json name="product_ids" store-api-aware="true" />
            <!--...-->
        </fields>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

I have tried to find custom entity by Status field and it works

```
{% set criteria = {
    'filter': [
        {
            "field": "status",
            "type": "equals",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
} %}
{% set blog = repoService.search('custom_entity_blog', criteria).first %}
```

but find custom entity by JSON field it return null

```
{% set criteria = {
    'filter': [
        {
            "field": "productIds",
            "type": "equalsAny",
            "value": [hook.page.product.id]
        }
    ]
} %}
{% set blog = repoService.search('custom_entity_blog', criteria).first %}
```

Anyone has the same problem or maybe I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a generic json field which may not contain a one-dimensional array, hence why the `EqualsAny` filter is incompatible with that field type.

There is the [`ListField`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/992c811bfba458fb429d7db69d0ae98001c29436/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Field/ListField.php) which is a confined json field that will only allow a list of values. That field would be compatible with the filter.

Unfortunately the [schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/System/CustomEntity/Xml/entity-1.0.xsd) for custom entities in apps currently does not allow the definition of list fields. If you can't rely on a regular plugin and it has to be an app, you'll have to resolve this programmatically as of today. You could also [create an issue ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/) asking for a future inclusion of the list field for custom entities in apps. If you have the time you could also try your hand on [creating a pull request](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/code/contribution) and [adding the missing field type](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/a75cfdbd4aa1adf6b3b7e670510dc3d4f0568b0f/src/Core/System/CustomEntity/Schema/SchemaUpdater.php#L182) yourself.

##### Alternative

Since you are trying to filter for an ID, it might be feasible to use a `ContainsFilter` instead, since the chance of mismatches is basically non-existing with IDs in particular.

```json
{
    "field": "productIds",
    "type": "contains",
    "value": hook.page.product.id
}
```

While not exactly a clean approach, this should work with json type fields and in your particular case.

Comment: Thanks @dneustadt! The alternative solution works for me. I will make PR for that field later.